# fitting deformable grid to image data

Tags: matrix, computer-vision, data-fitting, topology

I am attempting to fit a grid to an image such as this:

[image]

Clearly, there is some discrepancy between the white lines and the horizontal lines of a perfectly square grid, as shown here, where in some cases, the white line traverses from one grid line to an adjacent one:

[image]

I am wondering if there is a simple method (in opencv or otherwise) for fitting the grid to this data, as there is for fitting a sine wave to scatter plot data.

Answer (score 0):

The OCR community has produced a huge amount of work in this area (Google Books would not otherwise be possible, for example).

You can google for methods. [Here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=2C0E43879A7F04E5E805E72D7172BE77?doi=10.1.1.121.3233&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is a good, if not recent, example.